# Trying to join table on foreign key, but output is incorrect. CRUD also not fully working

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Here is my code:

**Tracks.cshtml.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Project.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Project.Pages
{
    public class TracksModel : PageModel
    {
        private Chinook db;

        public TracksModel(Chinook injectedContext)
        {
            db = injectedContext;
        }
        public IEnumerable<Track> Tracks { get; set; }
        public void OnGetAsync()
        {
            ViewData["Title"] = "Chinook Web Site - Tracks";
            Tracks = db.Tracks.Include(a => a.Album)
            .Include(a => a.Artist);
        }
        [BindProperty]
        public Track Track { get; set; }

        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Tracks.Add(Track);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToPage("/tracks");
            }
            return Page();
        }

        public IActionResult DeleteTrack(int TrackId)
        {
            var track = db.Tracks.Find(TrackId);

            if (track == null) return Page();

            db.Tracks.Remove(track); db.SaveChanges(); return RedirectToPage("/tracks");
        }
    }
}
```

**Tracks.cshtml**

```
@page
@using Project.Models
@model Project.Pages.TracksModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<div class="row">
    <h1 class="display-2">Tracks</h1>
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
            <tr>
                <th>Artist name</th>
                <th>Album name</th>
                <th>Track ID</th>
                <th>Track name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach (Track track in Model.Tracks)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelArtists => track.Artist.Name)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelAlbums => track.Album.Title)</td>
                    <td>@track.TrackId</td>
                    <td>@track.Name</td>
                    <td><a asp-page="/Tracks/Details" asp-route-id="@track.TrackId">Details</a></td>
                    <td><a asp-page="/Tracks/Edit" asp-route-id="@track.TrackId">Edit</a></td>
                    <td><a asp-page="/Tracks/Delete" asp-route-id="@track.TrackId">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <p>Enter a name & TrackID for a new track:&nbsp;</p>
    <form method="POST">
        <div><input asp-for="Track.Name" /></div>
        <div><input asp-for="Track.TrackId" /></div>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
</div>
```

**AlbumTracks.cshtml.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Project.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Project.Pages
{
    public class AlbumTracksModel : PageModel
    {
        private Chinook db;

        public AlbumTracksModel(Chinook injectedContext)
        {
            db = injectedContext;
        }
        public IEnumerable<Track> Tracks { get; set; }
        public void OnGetAsync(int id)
        {
            ViewData["Title"] = "Chinook Web Site - Tracks";
            Tracks = db.Tracks.Include(a => a.Album).Where(a => a.AlbumId == id);
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Track Track { get; set; }

        public IActionResult OnPost(int id)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Tracks.Add(Track);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToPage("/Albums/AlbumTracks?id=" + id);
            }
            return Page();
        }

        public IActionResult DeleteTrack(int TrackId, int id)
        {
            var track = db.Tracks.Find(TrackId);

            if (track == null) return Page();

            db.Tracks.Remove(track);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToPage("/Albums/AlbumTracks?id=" + id);
        }
    }
}
```

**AlbumTracks.cshtml**

```
@page
@using Project.Models
@model Project.Pages.AlbumTracksModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<div class="row">
    <h1 class="display-2">Tracks</h1>
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
            <tr>
                <th>Track ID</th>
                <th>Track name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach (Track track in Model.Tracks)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@track.TrackId</td>
                    <td>@track.Name</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <p>Enter a name & ID for a new track:&nbsp;</p>
    <form method="POST">
        <div><input asp-for="Track.Name" /></div>
        <div><input asp-for="Track.TrackId" /></div>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
</div>
```

I should explain that `ArtistId` is a foreign key of the `Albums` table, and `AlbumId` is a foreign key of the `Tracks` table.

The artist data is coming through to `/Tracks`, but there's something wrong, as all of the output are artists beginning with the letter A. So it seems like each artist name is being repeated many more times than it should?

There is another problem with my code, as I noticed that when I try to add a track from the `/AlbumTracks` page I have also created, that I get a 'page not found' error for the redirect page, even though the URL appears to be valid. The tracks are added though.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/double-happ1ness/chinook)

Edit: I've decided to forget about adding a track from `/Tracks`. I think it makes a lot more sense to just add them from `/AlbumTracks` instead.

Edit2: the redirection issue is sorted now. I needed to do

```
        return RedirectToPage("/Albums/AlbumTracks", new {id = id });
```

So now I need to able to add tracks as part of albums next.

Edit3: I've actually got it working like this:

```
    <div><input asp-for="Track.Name" /></div>
    <div><input asp-for="Track.TrackId" /></div>
    <div><input asp-for="Track.AlbumId" /></div>
```

It's just obviously not ideal to make the user manually enter the `AlbumId` of the Album they want to add a track to. It would be better to have the system take the `AlbumId` directly from the URL, as in

```
 https://localhost:5001/Albums/AlbumTracks?id=361
```

Comment: Is there still an issue, or have you solved this on your own?

Comment: Well, I came up with a 'workaround', which at least demonstrates that the database can be updated correctly as things stand. But it's obviously not ideal for users to have to manually enter the `AlbumId` value correctly for the edit to work. I'd really prefer an automated solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The first way**:

When you get into the `Albums/AlbumTracks?id=361` page, you could see the tracks list which `AlbumId` equals to 361. If you post the form in this page, the request url is still `Albums/AlbumTracks?id=361`. So the `id` you get in post handler is the `AlbumId` you want. Change your **AlbumTracks.cshtml.cs** like below:

```
public class AlbumTracksModel : PageModel
{
    //...
    public IEnumerable<Track> Tracks { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public Track Track { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnPost(int id)
    {
        Track.AlbumId = id;  //set the albumid by the request url...
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Tracks.Add(Track);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToPage("/Albums/AlbumTracks", new { id = id });
        }
        return RedirectToPage("/Albums/AlbumTracks", new { id = id });
    }
```

**Another way** is that you could set an input with the `AlbumId` when the page load. The `AlbumTracks.cshtml` rendered the Tracks for specific `AlbumId` and they all own the same `AlbumId`. You could just read the `AlbumId` like below in **AlbumTracks.cshtml**:

```
@page
@using Project.Models
@model Project.Pages.AlbumTracksModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers    
<div class="row">
    <h1 class="display-2">Tracks</h1>
    <table class="table">
        //....
    </table>
</div>
 <div class="row">
    <p>Enter a name & TrackID for a new track:&nbsp;</p>
    <form method="POST">
        <div><input asp-for="Track.Name" /></div>
        <div><input asp-for="Track.TrackId" /></div>

        //add this....
        <div><input asp-for="Tracks.ElementAt(0).AlbumId" name="Track.AlbumId" /></div>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Both of the two ways you could get the `AlbumId`.

Comment: Ah, that's brilliant, many thanks. The things I'm not very clear on though are what is `ElementAt(0)` for, and also why is `name=` needed? If anyone could tell me the pseudocode for that line that would be great, like what exactly is that line doing/saying? Thanks again.

Comment: Model binding system will bind the model by matching the `name`. `asp-for` will auto generate `name` and `id` element, it generates `name=Tracks.ElementAt(0).AlbumId` but it does not match the model property. That is why you need specify the `name`. `ElementAt(0)` is used to returns the element at a specified index in a sequence.Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementat?view=net-5.0